# Given a diagram of $f(x)$, how do you find $f^{-1}(-1)$?

Tags: graphing-functions, inverse

A question has a diagram of function f, with no function given (please ignore the purple line):
[image]

If I wanted to find $f^{-1}(-1)$, would I draw the inverse of f along the x=y line and then find what $y$ is at $x=-1$?

So in this case, would the answer be $f^{-1}(-1)=5$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(-1)=\{\text{all }x's \in \text{domain}\{f\} \text{ such that } f(x)=-1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are plotting the function $y=f(x)$, draw the line $y=-1$ on the same diagram. The points where the line cuts the graph of $f$ are the points $(f^{-1}(-1),-1)$. You just need to draw vertical lines on each of those points to get the corresponding values for $x$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added the picture of the graph. So in this case, would the answer be 5?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 0):

$y= f^{-1}(x)$ is, by definition, the number, y, such that x= f(y).  Given the graph of f (which is, I think, what you mean by "diagram"), start by marking the given value of x on the **y**- axis, go horizontally to the graph then then vertically to the x-axis to determine the value of y.  The point is that taking the **inverse** function "swaps" x and y.

Answer (score 0):

It may help for you to think that you want to find $x = f^{-1}(-1)$ so applying $f$ to both sides, we get $$f(f^{-1}(-1)) = f(x)$$ But we know that $f f^{-1} (m) = m$ so we get $$f(x) = -1$$ which is something I'm sure you can do.